# Upshot helper extension using Linq To Sql

Tags: linq-to-sql, upshot, asp.net-spa

This is my first question on SO, so please bear with any mistakes/irregularities.

I wanted to implement SPA for my new project, Hence I reached Steve Sandersion's after some googling [blog](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2012/03/06/single-page-application-packages-and-samples/).

Looking at the code hosted on github, I noticed that I had to use EF to use **Upshot**, but my DAL is already written in Linq to Sql, which will be very tiresome to migrate to EF.

So my questions are as below

> 1. Has anyone successfully used upshot with L2S? If yes some example would help.
> 2. Is there any other way to implement the SPA without upshot so that I can reuse my DAL in L2S?

**Edited**

I just found today that this question stands useless, as using upshot will not be feasible. Microsoft has stopped working on Upshot.**Some one please close this question.**

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. Microsoft has made it sure that people using Linq-to-sql don't survive.
Better use something like jquery and web api with some js mvvm libraries.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this should be possible. When using upshot you don't need to use entity framework, you can do the wireing for your self.

In my [ria 4 html demo](http://ria4htmldemo.codeplex.com/), I make use of ria services to get the data from the server to the upshot client. This way it doesn't depend on the DAL you have. Ria services works by conventions, meaning insert, update and remove methods are present on every domaincontext and you can implement them as you want. For more info you can read [this blogpost](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/04/upshotjs-knockoutjs-html5-client-for.html) on setting everything up. And [this](http://www.kristofdegrave.be/2012/04/crud-operations-with-wcf-ria-services.html) on for the CRUD operations.

Comment: I checked your demo. It really looks gr8. Do you know of any documentation for Upshot? Thanks

Comment: Well, this could be an issue. MS recently decided to suspend the upshot development for an unknow time. So the most information you will find is on blogs like mine. I can give you an other framework that does the same "breeze.js" (http://www.breezejs.com/). But I haven't got a chance to take a closer look at it.